# How do I get the equivalent index of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, equivalent

Here, I have two arrays.

```
let x = [0, 1, 2]
let y = [3, 4, 5]
```

What is the code so that when I input an index of array x, I get array y's equivalent? So like, I want to output 3 when I input x[0].

Comment: Obviously `y[0]`. But I think you want something please provide additional context and anexample

Comment: Are you literally typing "x[0]" as input? Or do you mean you type "0" as input and need to find it in the `x` array? If so, then I suggest you do some googling about how to get the index of an element in an array. Google will answer this very quickly.

Comment: Or are you typing "0" and want the element from that index in `x`? And then what do you want to do from there? Your question is very unclear about what you are inputting and what you mean by "y's equivalent". Please provide more details to clarify what you want to do. You should include some code that shows how you are inputing a value and what you want to use that value for.

Answer (score 0):

You can index y array with x elements (i is equals to x[i] in your case, is it wanted?) `y[x[i]]` or `y[i]`

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a new item in array x using push operation ie. x.push(val), then corresponding element in array y will be:

```
     y[x.length-1];
```

Answer (score -1):

I have an array: `y[x[i]]`

but check for index range for array Y else you will get undefined.